# Why can't create a new vue component in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I create new 3 components: `PlayerIndex.vue`,`PlayerCreate.vue`,`PlayerEdit.vue`

This is : `PlayerIndex.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <router-link :to="{name: 'createPlayer'}" class="btn btn-success">Create new player</router-link>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Players list</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Points</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="player, index in players">
                        <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ player.points }}</td>
                     
                        <td>
                            <router-link :to="{name: 'editPlayer', params: {id: player.id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
                                Edit
                            </router-link>
                            <a href="#"
                               class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                               v-on:click="deleteEntry(player.id, index)">
                                Delete
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                players: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            var app = this;
            axios.get('/players')
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.players = resp.data;
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    alert("Could not load players");
                });
        },
        methods: {
            deleteEntry(id, index) {
                if (confirm("Do you really want to delete it?")) {
                    var app = this;
                    axios.delete('/players/' + id)
                        .then(function (resp) {
                            app.players.splice(index, 1);
                        })
                        .catch(function (resp) {
                            alert("Could not delete players");
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my setting in `resource/js/app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');   
 
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('playerIndex', require('./components/PlayerIndex.vue').default);
//import PlayerIndex from './components/PlayerIndex.vue';
import PlayerCreate from './components/PlayerCreate.vue';
import PlayerEdit from './components/PlayerEdit.vue';

const routes = [    
    {path: '/players/create', component: PlayerCreate, name: 'createPlayer'},
    {path: '/players/edit/:id', component: PlayerEdit, name: 'editPlayer'},
]   


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

I using new components in home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

       
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="content" id="app">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Laravel
            </div>
            <example-component></example-component>
            <playerIndex></playerIndex>
        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:
`example-component` can load ok.

`playerIndex` can't load.

[image]

Why can't register new components?

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` (or `npm run watch`) to compile your assets? Have you tried using `player-index` as name of your component?

Comment: probably just need to use dash `-` name. HTML tags should not have capitals in them I believe.

Comment: Yes, i had execute, it had exist in public/js/app.js

Comment: oh, my god, thank you, i change name to player-index, it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue has naming convention.

**Won't work**

app.js

```
Vue.component('playerIndex', require('./components/PlayerIndex.vue').default);
```

html

```
<playerIndex></playerIndex>
```

**Will, should, work**

app.js

```
 Vue.component('player-index', require('./components/PlayerIndex.vue').default);
```

html

```
<player-index></player-index>
```

---

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

Comment: player-Index not ok, player-index is ok.

Comment: Yes, I noticed my typo just before your comment, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your component in a way and using it in a different

change

```
Vue.component('playerIndex', require('./components/PlayerIndex.vue').default);
```

to

```
Vue.component('player-index', require('./components/PlayerIndex.vue').default);
```

and use it in you template with:

```
 <player-index></player-index>
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated above `player-index` is the correct form because Vue needs valid HTML inside of it's template.

`<PlayerIndex/>` may also be an alternative if you do prefer it.

More details in the [official style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended).